# Save file with different extension javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, save

So, I'm currently saving a file with .TXT extension, but I would like to change it to save a .INI extension.

I'm using this code on my js to save a .TXT file:

```
blob = new Blob([file], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"})
        saveAs(blob, name)
```

This .INI extension can be edited with notepad, so I would like to know if it is possible to download a file with .INI extension.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? That would seem like a good starting point!

Comment: @RiggsFolly — Tried what? The code they said creates a file with a .txt extension?

Comment: @Quentin Tried `dancing in the moonlight` of course

Comment: `saveAs(blob, "inifile.ini")` of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't posted the implementation for the saveAs function, there really is no way to know how it works.  I would try the following:

```
var name = 'myfile.ini';
blob = new Blob([file], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, name);
```

That's the best I can say without knowing the library that you're using and how it's implemented.